# C++ destructor called twice with stack allocated compound objects

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a compound class (instance containing other instance, nor pointer, nor reference).
When the container instance is destroyed, destructor of contained instance is called (I am ok with that, it's logic). But the issue is that if the contained instance is stack allocated destructor is called once again when reaching out of scope.

Is that a coding error or a compiler issue?

What is the cleanest way of fixing it?

Here is my sample:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class A {
public:
  int i;
  A(int i_) : i(i_) {
    cout << "A(): " << i << endl;
  }
  ~A() {
    cout << "~A(): " << i << endl;
  }
};

class B {
public:
  A a;
  int b;
  B(const A& a_) : a(a_) {
    cout << "B(): " << a.i << endl;
  }
  ~B() {
    cout << "~B(): " << a.i << endl;
  }
};

int main(void) {
  for(int c = 0; c < 3; ++c) {
    A a(c+1);
    B b(a);
    cout << b.a.i << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
A(): 1
B(): 1
1
~B(): 1
~A(): 1
~A(): 1
A(): 2
B(): 2
2
~B(): 2
~A(): 2
~A(): 2
A(): 3
B(): 3
3
~B(): 3
~A(): 3
~A(): 3
```

Compiler is gcc 7.3.0

Comment: B contains an A .... it just doesn't call the constructor you think it should

Comment: You already know that `~B` calls `~A`. But in addition to instance of `B`, you have an another free instance of `A`. So two instances of `A`: one free, one inside of `B`. Destructors for both are called.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716209/what-operators-do-i-have-to-overload-to-see-all-operations-when-passing-an-objec

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem here?

Comment: When tracking constructor/destructor calls, don't forget copy/move constructor.

Answer (score 4):

The destructor is only called once per object. What you don't see in your output is that when you construct `b`, you create a *copy* of `a` using the copy constructor (which in your case is compiler-generated). That doesn't produce any output, but of course the destructor of the copy is also called.

If we add output to the copy constructor, we can see what actually happens:

```
A(const A& a_) : i(a_.i) {
  cout << "A(const A&): " << i << endl;
}
```

The output shows that each `A` is copied once, leading to the "duplicated" (not really) destructor calls ([**live demo**](https://ideone.com/XGxuQI)). If you want to avoid copying the object, look into C++11's `std::move`, which is explained in depth [elsewhere on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3106110/1106415).