# C++ destructor destroys objects couple times

Tags: c++, destructor

I am new in C++ so have a question.

There is C++ code:

```
class Test
{        
    public:
        std::string name;
        Test(){};
        Test(std::string name) {
        
            std::cout << "Create " << name << '\n';
            Test::name = name;
        };
        ~Test() {std::cout << "Destroy " << name << '\n';} 
};

std::vector<Test> test {Test("one"), Test("two"), Test("three")};

void main()
{
    for (auto i : test)
        std::cout << i.name << '\n';
    
    std::cout << "Clear\n";
    test.clear();
}
```

And this is output:

```
Create one
Create two
Create three
Destroy three
Destroy two
Destroy one
one
Destroy one
two
Destroy two
three
Destroy three
Clear
Destroy one
Destroy two
Destroy three
```

Why compiler destroy objects in vector couple times, when must do it once? What wrong in that code?

Compile Microsoft cl.exe x64 with default options.

Comment: you are not counting the copies that are created in the loop

Comment: Add a copy constructor that also prints a message.

Comment: You should always display the value of `this` when you try to control creation and destruction, because the compiler can generate and use copy or move destructors. Having `this` is the only foolproof way to know what object is being actually destroyed.

Comment: almost duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716209/what-operators-do-i-have-to-overload-to-see-all-operations-when-passing-an-objec its not quite up to date, but sufficient for this case

Comment: well, actually with the answer it is uptodate I think

Comment: In your for loop you are making a copy from the objects in the vector. If you use a reference after out you will force the use of references instead of copies.

Comment: Change your loop from `auto` to `auto&` (this will avoid the copy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's add a copy constructor (and use a smaller test case, to cut the verbosity) and see what happens...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Test
{        
    public:
        std::string name;
        Test(){};
        Test(std::string name) : name(name) {        
            std::cout << "New " << name << '\n';
        }
        Test(const Test& other) : name("Copy of " + other.name) {
            std::cout << "Copied " << other.name << '\n';
        }
        ~Test() {std::cout << "Destroy " << name << '\n';} 
};

std::vector<Test> test {Test("Original") };

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Loop:\n";
    for (auto i : test)
        std::cout << "This is " << i.name << '\n';   
    std::cout << "Clear\n";
    test.clear();
}
```

This produces

```
New Original
Copied Original
Destroy Original
Loop:
Copied Copy of Original
This is Copy of Copy of Original
Destroy Copy of Copy of Original
Clear
Destroy Copy of Original
```

Explanation:

```
New Original -- The object in the initialzer list
Copied Original -- Here it gets copied into the vector
Destroy Original -- The original is destroyed along with the initializer list
Loop:
Copied Copy of Original -- Copied into the loop variable
This is Copy of Copy of Original -- Printing in the loop
Destroy Copy of Copy of Original -- The temporary loop object is destroyed
Clear
Destroy Copy of Original -- Clearing the vector
```

If you loop over references, `i` will refer to the object inside the vector instead of a copy of it - just changing one line to

```
for (auto& i : test)
```

changes the output to

```
New Original
Copied Original
Destroy Original
Loop:
This is Copy of Original
Clear
Destroy Copy of Original
```

And you can get rid of further copying by creating the object inside the vector directly:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Test> test;
    test.emplace_back("Original");
    std::cout << "Loop:\n";
    for (auto& i : test)
        std::cout << "This is " << i.name << '\n';   
    std::cout << "Clear\n";
    test.clear();
}
```

Output:

```
Original
Loop:
This is Original
Clear
Destroy Original
```

Comment: Thank a lot! Now its clear.

Answer (score 0):

> What wrong in that code?

`main` must return `int`. It must not return `void`. To fix this, change the return type to `int`

Other than that, your expectations are wrong.

When you create a variable or a temporary object, it will be destroyed. When you create a copy of an object, both the copy and the original object will be destroyed eventually (except for cases involving memory leaks).

Answer (score 0):

Because in the `for` loop:

```
for (auto i : test)
    std::cout << i.name << '\n';
```

you're actually creating another copy of the `Test` elements in `std::vector<Test> test`, not the element itself, so that's why it creates (and destroys another copy)

Change your `for` loop to:

```
for (auto &i : test) // reference:
    std::cout << i.name << '\n';
```

produce:

```
Create one
Create two
Create three
Destroy three
Destroy two
Destroy one
one
two
three
Clear
Destroy one
Destroy two
Destroy three
```

which is what you expect:

[Try it live](https://godbolt.org/z/15oMejPrW) (including all the proper headers)

---

Also, `main()` returns an `int`, so change your `main()` definition to:

```cpp
int main()
```

Answer (score 0):

`int main()` not `void main()`.  Your compiler should have warned you about that.  Make sure you enable your compiler warnings.

`for (auto i : test)` makes a **copy** of the object.  You probably wanted `for (auto&& i : test)` or `for (auto const& i : test)`.  Note that `auto&&` has a bit of a different meaning than `Test&&`, since `auto&&` follows the *template* rules.

The code neglects to consider the implicit *copy constructor*.  Here I've added one in, which should help significantly for understanding what is going on:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct Test {
    std::string name;

    ~Test() {
        std::cout << "Destroy " << name << "\n";
    }

    Test() {
        std::cout << "Default-Create (empty)\n";
    }

    Test(std::string name_) : name{std::move(name_)} {
        std::cout << "Create " << name << "\n";
    }

    Test(Test const& other) : name{other.name + "!"} {
        std::cout << "Create-by-Copy " << name << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    auto test = std::vector<Test>{Test{"one"}, Test{"two"}, Test{"three"}};

    for (auto i : test)
        std::cout << i.name << "\n";

    std::cout << "Clear\n";
    test.clear();
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on Test&& and auto&& difference?

Comment: @ygroeg • I refer you to Howard Hinnant's response:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13130795/4641116 or more in depth explanation by Jonathan Boccara: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2021/04/02/what-auto-means/